# python 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
print(bsObj.find(id="mv-content-text").findAll("p")[0])
```

I use python3.6 to practice scrapy. the code is from the book,Web Scraping with Pyhon. why can't use find.().findAll()

Comment: I guess `bsObj.find(id="mv-content-text")` returns `None` when it doesn't find anything?

Comment: be sure `#mv-content-text` exists

Comment: Thanks,trouble has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `find(...)` has returned None as a tag with `id=mv-content-text` wasn't found in the bsObj.

You can only call `findAll` on a bs4 object. You can explore what's going on here using a combination of `type` and `hasattr` to poke at the returned values inside a REPL

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

>>> doc = ['<html><head><title>Page title</title></head>',
...        '<body><p id="firstpara" align="center">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.',
...        '<p id="secondpara" align="blah">This is paragraph <b>two</b>.',
...        '</html>']
... 

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(doc), "lxml")

>>> tag = soup.find(id="firstpara")

>>> tag
<p align="center" id="firstpara">This is paragraph <b>one</b>.</p>

>>> type(tag)
bs4.element.Tag

>>> hasattr(tag, 'findAll')
True
```

Attemping the same, but with a tag that doesn't exist within the HTML soup

```
>>> other = soup.find(id="non-existant")

>>> other

>>> type(other)
NoneType

>>> hasattr(other, 'findAll')
False
```

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely，trouble has been done.